# Browser (any) on Windows 7 loads bad (localhost) https certificate

Tags: windows-7, browser, ssl, certificate, localhost

On Windows 7 in Chrome, but also in any other browser, for one particular (external) website a bad HTTPS certificate is loaded.

When I open the certificate it says that Windows does not have enough information to validate that certificate. Also, the issuer is "localhost CA" and issued for "localhost". The path to the certificate is localhost and I can't find this certificate among others in Certificate Manager.

I suspect this is caused by some authority-creating testing, however, I don't remember the causing procedure...

Also I am a bit confused that a certificate issued for localhost is loaded when visiting some external website... Other websites (even with the same system) work and validate properly.

When would I find settings that would contain this issue-cause?

How would I delete a localhost certificate on WIndows 7?

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** On other devices the RIGHT (original) certificate is loaded, this is just a device-local issue. :-)

Answer (score -1):

That particular website certificate is a self signed certificate. One can create a self signed certificate for hostname "localhost",and can apply on their webserver. But all latest browser shows warning / or will not allow you to view that website, if the viewing website does not have a SSL certificate or using self signed certificate.Only solution for this is getting a genuine SSL certificates from certificate authorities like Verisign and apply on to that website webserver.

There is no issue on your Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Let me clear one thing up - on other computers it loads different (original) certificate ! So it really IS a device-local issue :-)